# How do you port forward with different external and internal ports

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I am aware of port forwarding with the same external and internal ports for example VPN settings would be

External Port - 1723

Internal Port - 1723

Device - 192.168.1.40

But I've seen setups like this

External Port - 23458

Internal Port - 1723

Device - 192.168.1.40

No matter how I've tried I can't seem to get this to work. How do you access a VPN with different External and Internal forwarded ports.

Comment: so just to be clear, what do forwarded ports and VPN have to do with each other that you are concerned about? they are not directly related and only a handful of situations would require both.  as for forwarding ports, when you forward a port on a router, you should be asked what internal and external port you want to use for the port forward rule. all traffic arriving on the routers wan at the external port, will be automatically sent to the internal address and port. I suppose its possible you have a router that doesn't ask you to specify an external and internal port, but that would be odd.

Answer (score 0):

You use the external port, actually you don't need to know the internal port. The router or VPN will automatically redirect to the internal port.

192.168.1.40:23458

Comment: I tried this already(`[public IP]:23458`), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might not be with different ports in general, but with you trying to use **PPTP** as your VPN protocol specifically. PPTP doesn't just run over a TCP connection – that's only the *control* channel.

The PPTP data channel uses a separate GRE tunnel, so the NAT needs to make special accomodations for VPN connections going through (just like it does for FTP) – and usually the "NAT helper" is only activated if the router sees activity on a specific port. In short, if the connection is to port 1723, the router applies its PPTP-specific NAT magic; if the connection is to any other port, it does not.

It is very possible that this check is done *before* the "port-forwarding" rules take place, so the router only recognizes PPTP connections if the *external* port is 1723.

(You could try configuring a static port-forwarding rule for GRE on your router, but most won't actually allow you to choose anything other than TCP or UDP, and GRE uses *neither* of those – it goes directly over IP as protocol 47.)

So my actual suggestion is to use another VPN protocol, as there are other reasons to avoid PPTP, not just this one (specifically: weak authentication and equally weak RC4-based encryption). For Windows clients, OpenVPN might be a good choice.

Comment: So the external and internal ports need to be the same (ie 1723) for Windows VPN to work?

Comment: Or try using Tailscale... it is surprisingly easy to set up